# hive shell shows many logs/warning in my hive 3.1.2

Tags: hadoop, hive

My hive shell(3.1.2) on hadoop 3.1 shows many log/warning on both start up and during execution of any queries.

### Startup

2020-05-10 12:10:26,988 INFO  [main] session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive-hduser/hduser/022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f/_tmp_space.db
2020-05-10 12:10:27,037 INFO  [main] conf.HiveConf: Using the default value passed in for log id: 022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f
2020-05-10 12:10:27,038 INFO  [main] session.SessionState: Updating thread name to 022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main
2020-05-10 12:10:30,631 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implementation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2020-05-10 12:10:30,779 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.autoStartMechanismMode is set to unsupported value null . Setting it to value: ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:30,791 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
2020-05-10 12:10:30,794 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] conf.MetastoreConf: Found configuration file file:/home/hduser/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf/hive-site.xml
2020-05-10 12:10:30,796 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] conf.MetastoreConf: Unable to find config file hivemetastore-site.xml
2020-05-10 12:10:30,797 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] conf.MetastoreConf: Found configuration file null
2020-05-10 12:10:30,799 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] conf.MetastoreConf: Unable to find config file metastore-site.xml
2020-05-10 12:10:30,799 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] conf.MetastoreConf: Found configuration file null
2020-05-10 12:10:31,951 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:35,553 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
2020-05-10 12:10:36,071 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is MYSQL
2020-05-10 12:10:36,077 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
2020-05-10 12:10:36,865 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:36,867 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:36,869 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:36,870 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:36,871 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:36,871 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:41,551 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:41,561 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:41,563 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:41,563 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:41,564 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:41,565 WARN  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
2020-05-10 12:10:46,889 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
2020-05-10 12:10:46,903 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
2020-05-10 12:10:46,992 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
2020-05-10 12:10:47,483 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient: RetryingMetaStoreClient proxy=class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient ugi=hduser (auth:SIMPLE) retries=1 delay=1 lifetime=0
2020-05-10 12:10:47,613 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_all_functions
2020-05-10 12:10:47,617 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hduser       ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_all_functions
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
2020-05-10 12:10:47,734 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] CliDriver: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.

## During execution

hive> show databases

> ;
>   2020-05-10 12:12:11,062 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] conf.HiveConf: Using the default value passed in for log id: 022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f
>   2020-05-10 12:12:11,356 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] ql.Driver: Compiling command(queryId=hduser_20200510121211_0213cb21-be5b-462d-9040-0f87736b9889): show databases

2020-05-10 12:12:13,078 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
2020-05-10 12:12:13,143 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] ql.Driver: Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)
2020-05-10 12:12:13,244 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] ql.Driver: Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:database_name, type:string, comment:from deserializer)], properties:null)
2020-05-10 12:12:14,270 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] exec.ListSinkOperator: Initializing operator LIST_SINK[0]
2020-05-10 12:12:14,295 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] ql.Driver: Completed compiling command(queryId=hduser_20200510121211_0213cb21-be5b-462d-9040-0f87736b9889); Time taken: 3.002 seconds
2020-05-10 12:12:14,297 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] reexec.ReExecDriver: Execution #1 of query
2020-05-10 12:12:14,298 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
2020-05-10 12:12:14,298 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] ql.Driver: Executing command(queryId=hduser_20200510121211_0213cb21-be5b-462d-9040-0f87736b9889): show databases

2020-05-10 12:12:14,328 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] ql.Driver: Starting task [Stage-0:DDL] in serial mode
2020-05-10 12:12:14,339 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_databases: @hive#
2020-05-10 12:12:14,339 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hduser       ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=get_databases: @hive#
2020-05-10 12:12:14,355 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] exec.DDLTask: results : 3
2020-05-10 12:12:14,407 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] ql.Driver: Completed executing command(queryId=hduser_20200510121211_0213cb21-be5b-462d-9040-0f87736b9889); Time taken: 0.109 seconds
OK
2020-05-10 12:12:14,408 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] ql.Driver: OK
2020-05-10 12:12:14,408 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
2020-05-10 12:12:14,427 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
2020-05-10 12:12:14,604 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2020-05-10 12:12:14,675 INFO  [022ddbe2-5580-4b63-be1b-2cd82dfe9f0f main] exec.ListSinkOperator: RECORDS_OUT_INTERMEDIATE:0, RECORDS_OUT_OPERATOR_LIST_SINK_0:3,
d1
default
demo
Time taken: 3.123 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)

Please advise on how to get rid of these messages.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here as the answer seems to be Hadoop 3.1.2 did not support the above mentioned version of hive.
Reinstalled Hadoop 3.3.0...

Comment: I'm very interested in how did you manage to find such information. I have a similar issue and would be glad if you had any source for it ?

Comment: Hi Kiwy, I checked on hive website for Hadoop/hive compatibility matrix. Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

add necessary log4j-sl4j jar files. I have also faced the same issue. Once you added jar files log and warn messages will get minimised.